# How to turn a shape into a button AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, button, adobe, addeventlistener

I have started making an advent calendar using the adobe flash professional software. I have drawn each 'door' individually with the draw tool on separate layers. I need to know how to use action script to wait for a click on one of the doors and then goto a specific layer and stop. I have tried different methods such as

> button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);

but it throws up errors.
Any ideas would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: post the errors. If it's a Shape object then it cannot listen to mouse event, make them a Sprite instead.

Comment: How would I make it a sprite?

Comment: var mysprite:Sprite = new Sprite();

Comment: Can I use transfer the shape into a sprite

Comment: mysprite.addChild(myshape);

Comment: Thanks very much. I worked out how to do it in the program by turning it into a symbol which functions as a button and changing 'button' to whatever name you call it.

Comment: @BotMaster... that akward moment when you have type into **Stackoverflow** how to `addChild` a shape!! How do you sleep at night?

Comment: @James... you should follow Botmaster's suggestion. If you drew this on the stage then convert to `MovieClip` since **Sprite** won't be available (I don't think). Use `myMC.buttonMode = true` to make it behave like a button. To change button "states" you simply move `myMC`'s internal timeline for example `myMC.gotoAndStop(2);` makes it go to frame 2 which might be a different colour (to suggest roll-over or click).

Comment: Also put your layers content into a "container" MovieClip. Basically all your code and content should be in one Flash frame and the code controls the container MovieClip to go to different frames/layers (instead of telling entire **Stage** to go to different frames, where you lose scope of previous code etc)

Answer (score 0):

If you drew the door it's still just a vector drawing that you can't really do anything with yet - you'll need to convert it to a MovieClip or a Sprite or a Button. The simple way to do this in the interface is:

1. Use the pointer to select everything you want to be contained in your MovieClip.
2. Press F8 OR choose "Modify" from the top menu and then "Convert to Symbol."

From there, you'll get a dialog box that looks like this:

[image]

You'll need to give it a name. This name will be the Class Name so call it something like "Door" or something descriptive like that. Leave the type as MovieClip and click "Ok."

Now you have the class so you'll have to give it an instance name. Select the object that you just created on the stage. In your properties it should look something like this:

[image]

Where it shows "instance name" delete that and give your object a name. In your code example you called it ***button*** so call it ***button*** here. Now you have an object that can listen for event listeners. Inside your handler you can write something like `this.gotoAndStop(2)` to get where you need to go.

Hope this helps!